# What is the starting date of the current Metonic cycle?

Tags: calendar

I am setting up an extensive hebrew calendar from hebrew year 3000.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_years):

> The Jewish calendar is based on the Metonic cycle of 19 years, of which 12 are common (non-leap) years of 12 months and 7 are leap years of 13 months. To determine whether a Jewish year is a leap year, one must find its position in the 19-year Metonic cycle. This position is calculated by dividing the Jewish year number by 19 and finding the remainder. (Since there is no year 0, a remainder of 0 indicates that the year is year 19 of the cycle.)

Thus the most recent Jewish year which gives a remainder of one is 5777 (as 5776 / 19 = 304).

So the current Metonic cycle began on Rosh HaShanah (1 Tishrei) 5777, corresponding to [3 October 2016](https://www.hebcal.com/converter/?hd=1&hm=Tishrei&hy=5777&h2g=1) (or to be more precise, sundown on 2 October 2016).

(As noted by Double AA in a comment, this is really just a matter of convention, to simplify calculations and to make sure that everyone is on the same page when discussing which years are leap years; there is no real significance to when each cycle of nineteen years 'starts'.)

Comment: The offset of 0 is one less thing to remember when you're davening on Rosh chodesh and realize you forgot to look up if it's a leap year before you started